# Angular 2 for loop

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to make a for loop to loop through my array but I cant make it work.

Here is what I have and what everything does.

```
export class BookingService {
    private config: Object;
    public domainSettings: Object = {};
    constructor(
        private http: Http,
        private kioskservice: KioskService
    ) { }

    public getAllBookings() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.http
                .get(
                    `${this.kioskservice.getAPIUrl()}search/dashboard/${this.kioskservice.LocationGUID()}/?apikey=${this.kioskservice.getAPIKey()}&format=json&from=2018-04-17&until=2018-04-18&full=true`
                )
                .toPromise()
                .then(
                    res => {
                        this.config = res.json()
                        console.log(res.json());
                        resolve();
                    },
                    msg => {
                        throw new Error("Couldn't get all Bookings: " + msg);
                    }
                );
        });
    }
```

The code above GETS an array from the HTTP request on the API. 
This is the array that is returned :

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0
:
AssignedUserProfile
:
null
BookUserGuid
:
"221443aa-d3c7-4543-b858-6a8710904ff8"
BookingRequestGuid
:
null
BookingStates
:
[{…}]
Channel
:
"Private"
CheckCancelAllowed
:
{Result: "BookingCancelDateInPast", Price: null}
CheckEditAllowed
:
{Result: "BookingSaveTimeStartDateInPastError", Price: null}
Coordinates
:
null
Culture
:
"nl-NL"
Customer
:
{Guid: "f2791b53-9db0-4e86-99c0-8f25c1242e72", Reference: null, Name: "  test", DirectUrl: "https://dev.api.timeblockr.local/v2/userprofiles/f2791b53-9db0-4e86-99c0-8f25c1242e72"}
CustomerGuid
:
"f2791b53-9db0-4e86-99c0-8f25c1242e72"
Dossier
:
{Guid: "8f37508d-5d34-4a0a-b08d-353a1c2600b9", Reference: null, Name: "", DirectUrl: "https://dev.api.timeblockr.local/v2/dossiers/8f37508d-5d34-4a0a-b08d-353a1c2600b9"}
DossierGuid
:
"8f37508d-5d34-4a0a-b08d-353a1c2600b9"
DossierState
:
"INIT"
DynamicFieldValues
:
(23) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
Guid
:
"3d28cd33-b7cf-40f6-85f2-157633bcf735"
Id
:
518478
InsertDate
:
"2018-04-17T10:54:08.457"
InvoiceId
:
null
IsPaymentBooking
:
false
Location
:
{Guid: "11325d9b-7b24-47ff-9ea3-509fe955dd55", Reference: null, Name: "CUHQ", DirectUrl: "https://dev.api.timeblockr.local/v2/locations/11325d9b-7b24-47ff-9ea3-509fe955dd55"}
LocationGuid
:
"11325d9b-7b24-47ff-9ea3-509fe955dd55"
Modules
:
[{…}]
Options
:
{BookingResourceitemPreference_Random: Array(1), BookingResourceitemPreference_SpecificChoicePrivate: Array(0), BookingResourceitemPreference_SpecificChoicePublic: Array(0)}
PaymentType
:
"NoPayment"
ProductUnits
:
[{…}]
Reference
:
null
ResourceItem
:
[{…}]
ResourceItemGuid
:
["90cce97d-a9c0-4ca3-8a2e-1f700590a93a"]
State
:
"Confirmed"
TicketNumber
:
"JM67"
TicketNumberDisplay
:
"JM67"
TimeEnd
:
"2018-04-17T12:30:00"
TimeStart
:
"2018-04-17T12:00:00"
__proto__
:
Object
```

I need to loop through the arrays and then choose the "TicketNumber" so I get a list with all Ticketnumbers instead of a list with all full Arrays. 
Can someone help me with how I can write that?

Comment: can you provide what you are getting in json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to assign somewhere array from response or try to map it directly to the destination array like that

```
this.ticketsArray = res.json.map(response=> {
  return response.ticket(I don't know how ticket number property is called in 
  response consider that it is the ticket)
}
```